# AngularJS $location object doesn't have the path() function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

For some reason my $location object doesn't have the path function when calling in my controller.

[image]

Someone an idea?

E: here the Controller

```
erpmApp.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$parse','$swipe', '$location', '$rootScope', 'Page', 'Data', 'Config', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $parse, $swipe, $location, Page, Data, Config) {

    Config.setHeadbarStatus(true);

    Page.setTitle('ERP-Mobile');

    $scope.dashboarddata = null;

    $scope.redirect = function(url) {
        console.log($location);
    };

    $scope.loadDashboard = function() {
        if($scope.dashboarddata == null) {
            Data.getDashboardMenuData().then(function(response){
                $scope.dashboarddata = response;
            }); 
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure ? Is this not the $scope ?, Can you post the code in the controller definition ?

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the scope

Comment: I added the controller definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your dependency names mixed up

```
['$scope', '$http',    '$parse','$swipe', '$location', '$rootScope', 'Page', 'Data', 'Config', function(
  $scope,   $rootScope, $http,   $parse,   $swipe,      $location,    Page,   Data, Config) {
```

Which means, what you assume is `$location` is actually `'$rootScope'`

Comment: I should take a break... thanks :D